# How to import existing MySQL database into web2py?

Tags: python, mysql, database, web2py

I am working on a project which requires that I import an already existing database and use it's data in Web2py. I have been able to link to the database by changing the DAL URI to:

```
db = DAL('mysql://root:password@localhost/database_name',pool_size=1,check_reserved=['all'])
```

and it creates all of my web2py defined fields just fine, and it can interact with them, but I can not access any of the data that was already in the database before. I tried running the web2py script extract_mysql_models.py, which is the supported way of importing the data but all I got returned was:

```
legacy_db = DAL('mysql://root:password@localhost/localhost/database_name')
```

which just creates another dal object. Trying to access anything through legacy_db only gives the same options as trying to get something through db. Has anyone done this before? Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. This is how I did.

1. dumping it from old db

   ```
   mysqldump --user USERNAME --password=PASSWORD dbname > backup.sql
   ```
2. importing backupfile to new mysql server

   ```
   mysql -h mysql.server -u USERNAME -p 'DBNAME' < backup.sql
   ```
3. Add add the DAL connection to new mysql server.

It is then identical to the old db. The problem I had was that setting up the db from pythonanywhere UI created a DB that was not identical with my old db. So if I remember right, you could also let web2py first create the db tables and then do step 2 last. Thats how I did anyways ... if I remember right ;) Hope it helps you. Cheers

Comment: This was what I was missing, the tables are defined in the database but they weren't defined in web2py. I was confused because the 'extract_mysql_models.py' only output one line but it was supposed to be an entire definition of every table. Thanks for helping point that out :).

For anyone else who stumbles across this, if 'extract_mysql_models.py' isn't working than try defining the tables on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the following function was created in appadmin.py to automatically create the table definitions

```
get_db():
    import re
    datyp = dict(
    bit='boolean', tinyint='boolean',
    smallint='integer', mediumint='integer', int='integer', bigint='bigint',
    decimal='decimal', double='double', float='double',
    char='password', varchar='string',
    longtext='list:string', mediumtext='text', text='text', tinytext='text',
    enum='json',
    timestamp='datetime', datetime='datetime', date='date', time='time',
    year='integer',
    tinyblob='blob', blob='blob', mediumblob='blob', longblob='blob',
    binary='blob', varbinary='blob'
    # upload    reference    list:string    list:integer    list:reference
    # json    big-id    big-reference
    )
    tdat = []
    tbls = [t[0] for t in db.executesql('SHOW TABLES;')]
    for tbl in tbls:
        cols = [k.strip() for k in db.executesql(
            'SHOW CREATE TABLE `' + tbl + '`;')[0][1].split('\n')]
        fname = OrderedDict()
        for col in cols:
            if col.startswith('KEY'):
                continue
            coln = re.findall('`([^`]*)`', col)
            if (col.startswith('`')):
                st = col.index(' ') + 1
                typ = col[st:col.index('(' if '(' in col else
                        (' ' if ' ' in col[st:] else ','), st)]
                ft = datyp[typ]
                if (ft == 'string'):
                    st = col.index('(', st) + 1
                    ft = "'" + ft + "', length=" + col[st:col.index(')', st)]
                elif (ft == 'decimal'):
                    st = col.index('(', st)
                    ft = "'" + ft + col[st:col.index(')', st) + 1] + "'"
                else:
                    ft = "'" + ft + "'"
                if (not "DEFAULT NULL" in col) and ("'" in col):
                    st = col.index("DEFAULT '") + len("DEFAULT '")
                    ft += ', default=' + col[st:col.index("'", st)]
                if 'NOT NULL' in col:
                    ft += ', required=True'
                fname.update({coln[0]: ft})
                continue
            if (len(coln) == 2 and col.startswith('UNIQUE KEY')):
                fname[coln[1]] += ', unique=True'
                continue
            if (len(coln) == 4):
                sval = fname[coln[1]]
                if 'integer' in sval:
                    sval = sval.replace('integer', 'reference db.' + coln[2])
                elif 'bigint' in sval:
                    sval = sval.replace('bigint',
                                        'big-reference db.' + coln[2])
                fname[coln[1]] = sval
                if ('ON DELETE ' in col) and  (not 'CASCADE' in col):
                    st = col.index("ON DELETE ") + len("ON DELETE ")
                    sval = ', ondelete="' + col[st:col.index(" ON", st)] + '"'
                    fname[coln[1]] += sval
        colstr = ["db.define_table('" + tbl + "',"]
        for key, val in fname.items():
            if (key == 'id'):
                continue
            colstr.append("Field('" + key + "', " + val + "),")
        colstr.append('migrate=False)')
        tdat.append(colstr)
    response.view = 'default/index.html'
    return dict(msg=tdat)
```